# ModX rev - Wayfinder меню с иконкой

Tags: html, modx, меню, иконки

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите начинающему, как в ModX вывести первый пункт меню с инкой.

Изучаю ModX, не могу понять. Варианты с выводом через класс не подходят, использую fortawesome. По той же причине отпадает css content.

Подскажите простой способ добавить HTML код в первый элемент меню через Wayfinder.

Кода в данный такой:

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &outerClass=`nav navbar-nav` ]]
```

Нужно добавить только к первому пункту:

```
<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
```

Comment: через css - :first-child и :before не пойдёт?

Answer (score 1):

Раз новичек - советую сразу перейти на pdomenu http://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdomenu - это полная замена wayfinder с дополнительными фишками. А задачку твою проче всего решить через плейсхолдер `[[+idx]]`:

```
[[pdoMenu?
     &startId=`0`
     &outerClass=`nav navbar-nav`
     &tpl=`my_row_tpl`
]]
```

чанк `my_row_tpl`:

```
<li[[+classes]]>[[+idx:eq=`1`:then=`<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> `:else=``]]<a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>
```

Comment: не помогло + первый пункт стал не кликабельный 
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li class="first"><a href="">AP</a></li><li class="active"><a href="news-line.html">ЛЕНТА</a></li><li><a href="generator.html">ГЕНЕРАТОР</a></li><li><a href="documentation.html">ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЯ</a></li><li class="last"><a href="repository.html">РЕПОЗИТОРИЙ</a></li></ul>

Comment: Значит ты чтото делаешь не так, потому что у меня всё работает... Проверь где ошибся. Вынеси в отдельный чанк шаблон строки и укажи в tpl имя чанка.

Comment: Внес изменения в ответ чтобы было понятней.

Comment: это у меня карма такая, ничего удивительного ) Второй вариант аналогичен первом, пункт не кликабельный, иконки нет.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9GEPcdTKTkVfjNVd3BFVG9LZHRieVBXbEIzQmdhdzFCSVJMdXRSLTBxaHpEdFU0V2htSE0&usp=sharing

Comment: Убери `@INLINE` и сделай через отдельный чанк как я написал. Тогда точно заработает. На тех скриншотах что ты скинул - там `@INLINE` в вызове сниппета стоит.